Aliases to files under /sites/default/files
I have a file currently accessible to web users with the following url:
https://mysite/sites/default/files/brochure_WEB.pdf
With the help of the Path module I want to create a URL alias to it. So,
in /config/search/path after pressing "Add Alias" I fill out the form
with the following information:
System path: /sites/default/files/brochure_WEB.pdf
URL alias: /docs/brochure.pdf
When I press "Save" I get the following error message:
Either the path '/sites/default/files/brochure_WEB.pdf' is invalid or
you do not have access to it.
Am I doing something wrong? Is "/sites/default/files/brochure_WEB.pdf" some
kind of alias implicitly provided by Drupal so I need to reference the files
under sites/default/files with a different URL?
Searches on the net did not provide any useful result. Such an alias should
be very common and very easy to create in Drupal. I would say that this
is basic functionality (you put files on the system in the public area and
you create an alias to immediately get them served by it).
One more clarification:
The file brochure_WEB.pdf can be placed under /sites/default/files in two
ways:

by manually copying the file in that folder;
by uploading it with the IMCE;

In the first case Drupal does not know about its existence. So the error message
is somehow understandable. But in the second case Drupal knows about the
existence of the file. However, the error message is present.
Is there any simple solution accessible through the user interface to create
an alias to an existing file that web users can already access with a URL?

Path aliases aren't for files, or I don't understand your question.

A redirect via the redirect module might be easier

Is that even possible with public files? I doubt it.

@unusedspoon It works with redirects (module redirect), but a redirect is not the same as an alias.

There is no concept of aliases in Drupal for public files as far as I know.

@monalisa It may not be possible. Other users suggested the same thing (because these files are served by Apache)

A redirect is as close as you'll get essentially out of the box. Your alternative would be to create a custom controller for /docs and then get the filename from the rest of the url and then manually serve the file up

You cannot create aliases for files (as far as I know).  What you can do is create an entity with a file field, and create an alias for that entity.
For example, with the core media module, you can create file entities (file media type) that have a file field.  Add your file to the field, and then you can set the alias to whatever you want on the media file entity edit screen.
You can also use the Pathauto module to automatically create aliases based on a pattern.
If you want to organize the file paths used when uploading files, you can use the File (Field) Paths module. Note that this module changes the file path in /sites/default/files; it does not change the alias (to change the alias, use Pathauto.)
